# Unbound record field for split_on_char OCaml

Tags: string, ocaml

This is the problem I'm working on:

Write a function `homePath : unit -> string list` that returns a list of the names of the directories in the path to your home directory. For example, on my computer the call `home ()` would return the list `["Users"; "Name"]`

This is what I have implemented so far:

```
let homePath () = 
 let string = Sys.getenv "PATH" in
 string.split_on_char "/" s
```

I get the error:

> Unbound record field split_on_char

I am new to OCaml so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```ml
let homePath () = 
 let string = Sys.getenv "PATH" in
 String.split_on_char '/' string
```

- You defined a variable `string`, not `s`
- Function `split_on_char` is in `String` module
- Type of `String.split_on_char` is `char -> string -> string list`, not `string -> string -> string list`. "/" is a string, not a char.